# loading image asynchronously with spinner at the back

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I see many apps which have an image frame that loads the image asynchronously and while the image is not loaded yet, it shows either a spinner at the back or a default image. Is there a library for doing that? If yes then what is it? And please no three20 (I've had a bad experience with it). If not then how do you create one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spinner is called `UIActivityIndicatorView`, which is a subclass of UIView, and as such, can be placed anywhere on the screen.

It has `startAnimating` and `stopAnimating` methods, which begin and end the "spin".

So create the UIActivityIndicatorView, place it with `addSubview` where you want, and call `startAnimating` (this, as UI activity, has to be done on the main thread). Then call the image loading code asynchronously, and when the image finishes loading, call `stopAnimating` on the spinner, put the loaded image on top of it, and then remove the spinner with `removeFromSuperview`.

Comment: yea I know what UIActivityIndicatorView is, was thinking if there was an integrated library that does this

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no built-in Cocoa API to do this in a call or two (which sounds like what you want).

I personally set up a singleton image cache manager that uses the built-in `NSURLConnection` class to load the images, save them to the filesystem, then call delegate methods on the requesting class (which includes a little subclass of `UIImageView`) to hand it the loaded image data.

People on SO report success with `ASIHTTPRequest` as well, for similar tasks. Worth checking out, I imagine (though I don't use it).